# Create select options and get the current values for month and date

Tags: php, html, html-select

```
<select name="year"><?=options(date('Y'),1900)?></select>
<select name="month"><?php echo date('m');?><?=options(1,12,'callback_month')?></select>
<select name="day"><?php echo date('d');?><?=options(1,31)?></select>
```

PHP

```
function options($from,$to,$callback=false)
{
    $reverse=false;

    if($from>$to)
    {
        $tmp=$from;
        $from=$to;
        $to=$tmp;

        $reverse=true;
    }

    $return_string=array();
    for($i=$from;$i<=$to;$i++)
    {
        $return_string[]='<option value="'.$i.'">'.($callback?$callback($i):$i).'</option>';
    }
    if($reverse)
    {
        $return_string=array_reverse($return_string);
    }

    return join('',$return_string);
}

function callback_month($month)
{
    return date('m',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1));
}
```

What should i make to get the current month and date in the corresponding dropdowns as starting values, as it is the case with years (2013).

Comment: You can pass in another parameter to options() function which is current year/current month. Inside the function where you are concatenating options for the drop down, check if current value in loop is same as paased parameter, add selected='selected' in the option

Comment: You should not call an array '$return_string'. For readability, call it '$options_array' or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following:

Added new param `type` to `options()` function

```
<select name="year"><?=options('year' ,date('Y'),1900)?></select>
<select name="month"><?php echo date('m');?><?=options('month', 1,12,'callback_month')?></select>
<select name="day"><?php echo date('d');?><?=options('day', 1,31)?></select>  

<?php

function options($type, $from,$to,$callback=false)
{
    $reverse=false;

    switch ($type)
    {
        case "year":
            $current = date('Y');
            break;
        case "month":
            $current = date('m');
            break;
        case "day":
            $current = date('d');
            break;
    }

    if($from>$to)
    {
        $tmp=$from;
        $from=$to;
        $to=$tmp;

        $reverse=true;
    }

    $return_string=array();
    for($i=$from;$i<=$to;$i++)
    {
        $selected = ($i == $current ? " selected" : "");
        $return_string[]='<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selected.'>'.($callback?$callback($i):$i).'</option>';
    }
    if($reverse)
    {
        $return_string=array_reverse($return_string);
    }

    return join('',$return_string);
}

function callback_month($month)
{
    return date('m',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just retreive the current date FIRST and use a for loop to subtract each year

Answer (score 1):

Use **`selected`** Attribute:

e.g.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dd3FU/

Just put it inside an `if statement`.

Enjoy!

Comment: joespina, do you mean something like: `if option value == date(m) then attr selected = true ?`

Comment: depends on you friend. if it was up to me I would just make it something like if(date == date now){ echo selected } else { echo something else }; Whatever makes you more comfortable would be better. The key element here is the `selected` attribute.